# Can I remove the linux-modules-extra packages for old kernel versions?

Tags: package-management, disk-usage

I am almost out of space in my root partition, and when I go check why, I realize that I have multiple linux-modules-extra packages installed, all of which are heavy, and have old kernel versions on them.

When I run

```
dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Installed-Size;10}\t${Package}\n' | sort -k1,1n
```

I get the following output for the last few packages:

```
168006  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic
168166  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-36-generic
168204  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-32-generic
174488  discord
176527  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-53-generic
176554  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-59-generic
176567  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-61-generic
176601  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-62-generic
176682  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-28-generic
176683  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-26-generic
176980  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic
177026  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic
177164  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-40-generic
177199  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic
177223  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-42-generic
179195  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic
179280  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-47-generic
179315  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-48-generic
179330  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-52-generic
179388  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-51-generic
233492  google-chrome-stable
243263  libgl1-mesa-dri
261334  libgl1-mesa-dri
296661  icaclient
328693  linux-firmware
```

My question is, can I delete all of the linux-modules-extra packages?

Answer (score 4):

**No, because most of those package are ALREADY uninstalled.**

"*Installed-Size*" means the size consumed IF the package were installed. Only a single version of any package can be installed at one time. All the others were uninstalled already, replaced by a newer version.

Let's take a look, using dpkg to list all known versions of that package:

- Look in the first column: `ii` means 'installed', `rc` means 'uninstalled'

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic      4.15.0-20.21                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-22-generic      4.15.0-22.24                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-23-generic      4.15.0-23.25                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-24-generic      4.15.0-24.26                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic      4.15.0-29.31                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-30-generic      4.15.0-30.32                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-32-generic      4.15.0-32.35                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-33-generic      4.15.0-33.36                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic      4.15.0-34.37                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic      4.15.0-36.39                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-10-generic      4.18.0-10.11                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-11-generic      4.18.0-11.12                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-12-generic      4.18.0-12.13                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-13-generic      4.18.0-13.14                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-14-generic      4.18.0-14.15                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic      4.18.0-15.16                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-16-generic      4.18.0-16.17                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-18-generic      4.18.0-18.19                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-13-generic       5.0.0-13.14                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-15-generic       5.0.0-15.16                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-16-generic       5.0.0-16.17                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-17-generic       5.0.0-17.18                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-19-generic       5.0.0-19.20                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-20-generic       5.0.0-20.21                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-21-generic       5.0.0-21.22                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-23-generic       5.0.0-23.24                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-25-generic       5.0.0-25.26                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-27-generic       5.0.0-27.28                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-29-generic       5.0.0-29.31                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-31-generic       5.0.0-31.33                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-32-generic       5.0.0-32.34                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-19-generic       5.3.0-19.20                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-22-generic       5.3.0-22.24                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-23-generic       5.3.0-23.25                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-24-generic       5.3.0-24.26                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-26-generic       5.3.0-26.28                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-29-generic       5.3.0-29.31                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-40-generic       5.3.0-40.32                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-42-generic       5.3.0-42.34                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic       5.3.0-45.37                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic       5.3.0-46.38                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.3.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic       5.4.0-26.30                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-28-generic       5.4.0-28.32                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-29-generic       5.4.0-29.33                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-31-generic       5.4.0-31.35                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-33-generic       5.4.0-33.37                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-37-generic       5.4.0-37.41                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-40-generic       5.4.0-40.44                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic       5.4.0-42.46                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-45-generic       5.4.0-45.49                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-47-generic       5.4.0-47.51                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-48-generic       5.4.0-48.52                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-51-generic       5.4.0-51.56                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Comment: technically rc is residual config - you could `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean` to tidy up a bit, if that doesn't help. a purge  of these packages by gui or cmd line might make things look a little more sane.

Comment: @Crighton the package database that `dpkg-l` uses would not be affected by any of those actions. The OP's output would be unchanged. "Purge" would do nothing useful either: l-m-e places no files in /etc.